# Giving AD group permissions to manage another AD group in Python

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, python-ldap, ldap3

I was trying to add permission for managing one AD group to another AD group via Python. In powershell its done by the "DSACLS" command and i was trying to find a way to do it in Python through the ldap3 module, but if its possible via any other library please mention that as well.

The powershell command i am trying to emulate look like this

dsacls \$domainController\$ownerGroupDN /G """$ownerGroupDN"":WPRP;member;"

I was trying to do the same but via Python to run it via AWS lambda.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't know about python-ldap / python, but if your only target is to resolve the problem, you can execute the said powershell command from your python program itself!

Comment: Hi, 
I know but the "DSACLS" needs a windows server, i was trying to make it stateless because the rest could be done as a lambda so if there was a way to do it without that it would be helpful, but thanks for the answer, i really appreciate it.